# Check which element is closest to the bottom of it's container. JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have the following page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class = "data" ></div>
    <div class = "data" ></div>
    <div class = "data" ></div>
<div>
```

Is there a way, with JS, jQuery or maybe CSS3, to check which 'data' div is at the bottom? ie, closest to the bottom of 'container'. And then add a class to that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the jQuery approach to assign a class to the last element with the data class

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.data').last().addClass("give class name");

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery:

```
var lastElement = $('.container .data:last-child');
lastElement.addClass('yourClass');
```

using native js:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
var lastElement = div.lastChild;
lastElement.className = lastElement.className + ' yourClass';
```

using css:

```
.container .data:last-child { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:last-child` selector available to you in CSS.

```
.data:last-child { }
```

Comment: Your js is wrong. the returned array from getElementsByClassName doesn't have a property 'lastChild'!

Comment: Yes, I removed my JS because I had the same feeling in my mind :)